# C++: Fast/parallel computation of L1 distance between two `std::vector<double>` vectors

Tags: c++, gpu, linear-algebra

I am working on a machine with an Nvidia GPU and Cuda8 and I have a C++ application that should compute the L1 distance between two vectors that are represented by `std::vector<double>`.

Currently, my code is not parallel at all and only uses the CPU:

```
double compute_l1_distance(const std::vector<double> &v1, const std::vector<double> &v2) {
    if (v1.size() != v2.size()) {
        return -1;
    }
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < v1.size() i++) {
        double val = v1[i] - v2[i];
        if (val < 0) {
            val = 0 - val;
        }
        result += val;
    }

    return result;
}
```

How can I improve the performance of this computation? How can I utilize the GPU? Are there recommended libraries that will do the job fast using the GPU or using any other optimization?

Comment: yes search for the thrust library

Comment: I will start with using STD::valarray as it's about linear algebra

Comment: Unless you have vectors with millions of entries, or unless you have millions of small vectors, the likelihood that GPU computing is on any way useful here is slim to say the least

Comment: @talonmies what you're saying is that the cost of copying the data to the GPU is not worth it? My vectors only have 4096 values

Comment: No. I'm saying that the GPU is a latency hiding architecture and you need a huge volume of parallel work to hide all that latency. 4096*2 double precision ops is about 7 or 8 orders of magnitude too small

Comment: My first suggestion would be to consider AVX. It operates on 4 doubles in parallel. That means it only needs 1024 iterations, not 4096. Also, `abs(x)` doesn't need a branch in AVX, as it's [`max(x,-x)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5993459/15416)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [thrust](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html) library, it would looks something like:

```
double compute_l1_distance(const std::vector<double> &v1, 
                           const std::vector<double> &v2) {
    if (v1.size() != v2.size()) {
        return -1;
    }
    thrust::device_vector<double> dv1 = v1;
    thrust::device_vector<double> dv2 = v2;
    auto begin = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(
                                               dv1.begin(), dv2.begin())); 
    auto end   = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(
                                               dv1.end(),   dv2.end()  )); 
    const auto l1 = [](const thrust::tuple<double,double>& arg) {
        return fabs(thrust::get<0>(arg) - thrust::get<1>(arg));
    }
    const auto add = [](double a, double b) { return a+b; }

    return thrust::transform_reduce(first, last, l1, 0.0, add);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `cuda` and `thrust` for utilizing the GPU. And as far as performance is concerned. Yes, it will be faster.

Please look in to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301309/can-should-i-run-this-code-on-a-gpu) post. It has a very clear description.

And if you have to call `compute_l1_distance` multiple times you can use `pthread` to call the method thus executing it in parallel.